# Celery- How to autoscale worker processes

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

I read from the celery documentation that we can autoscale concurrency by using autoscale option while starting a worker.

I have added 200 task in my queue and each task takes 5seconds to finish. I started worker with autoscale of 3 min concurrency and 15 max concurrency , but its starting with only 3 processes and I am not seeing any scale up in the number of processes.

Using celery with rabbitmq.

Comment: I found the relevant Github issue here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4003